# async map overwriting the array objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I have an array on which async.map has to run. The functionality is fine in terms of parallel run on each array object, which is logged as "Result for ...". But, the return callback from iterative function seems to be overwriting the first array object with the result of last object that was prepared, which is logged as "Final Result...".

```
async.map(array, getInfo, function (asyncError, asyncStatus) 
{        
    if(asyncError)
    {
        return callback(asyncError);           
    }
    else
    {
        console.log(' Final Result <<<<<<<<<<<------- '+JSON.stringify(asyncStatus));
        //return callback(null, asyncStatus);  
    }
});

function getInfo(passedArray, callback) 
{
    Analyser(passedArray.productName, passedArray.productPurchaseRecord, function(opError, opStatus)
    {
        if(opError)
        {
            return callback(opError);           
        }
        else
        {  
            console.log(' Result for '+passedArray.productName+' ------->>>>>> '+JSON.stringify(opStatus));
            return callback(null, opStatus);  
        }
    });            
}
```

Output:-

```
Result for bmwX1 ------->>>>>> [{"month":"January","totalSales":8,"newOrders":3}]
Result for AudiA4 ------->>>>>> [{"month":"January","totalSales":11,"newOrders":4}]
Final Result <<<<<<<<<<<------- [[{"month":"January","totalSales":8,"newOrders":3}],[{"month":"January","totalSales":8,"newOrders":3}]]
```

Comment: What is `Analyser`? Could it possible be re-using objects? Your async logic looks fine to me.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Analyser is a sub functionality that uses the passedArray objects for some data breakup/analysis and returns an array, which is received by "opStatus" and is printed as " Result for …" 
[Sidebar] I have tried the async each approach. It also seems to have a problem, although there, I am pushing objects to an array whenever the parallel control flow in each returns with an object. Problem seems to be at a point when push is done, where the last object pushed in one common array is overwriting all other objects, where size of the array is maintained as "n" objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`scramjet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) and [ES6 async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Your code would look somewhat like this:

```
try {
    const result = await scramjet.fromArray(array)
        .reduce(async (last, item) => getInfo(item))
} catch (e) {
    console.error("error", e)
}
```

You'd need to change the getingo function a little, to be asynchronous like this:

```
async function getInfo(passedArray, callback) {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
        Analyser(passedArray.productName, passedArray.productPurchaseRecord, 
            function(opError, opStatus) {
                if(opError) {
                    return reject(opError);
                } else {
                    console.log(' Result for '+passedArray.productName+' ------->>>>>> '+JSON.stringify(opStatus));
                    return resolve(opStatus);
               }
        });
}
```

That gives a nice, clean code, and the code is run one by one (and you can use map, if you'd like to run the code in parallel). The reduce method runs very much like `Array.prototype.reduce`